# Unable to create Anonymous Type with two same name property

Tags: linq-to-entities, vb.net-2010, anonymous-types

I have simple linq query with join statement results in anonymous type. The problem is two properties have same name. How to get this to work. 
Suppose I have the following code

```
Dim retQry = From cb In _entityCtx.CandyBars
             Join soda in _entityCtx.Drinks
             On cb.Id Equals soda.Id
             Select cb.Id, Soda.Id, Soda.Price, cb.Name
```

I get the error Range variable Id is already declared.

UPDATE: Found microsoft document that shows only property name is used hence 'Id' is field that gets passed around. 
In anonymous types from query express
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx

Comment: Not sure about the syntax, but you can explicitly specify a property name. So use `cbId` and `SodaId`, in C# it is like `select new { cbId = cb.Id, SodaId = soda.Id....`

Comment: `Select new { cbid = cd.Id, sodaid= Soda.Id, ...` ?

Comment: Thanks Habib and Giorgos and dotnetom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use 2 properties with the same name, but you can use select and create anonymous type with 2 properties with different names like this:

```
Select New With {.cbId = cb.Id, .SodaId = Soda.Id, .Price = Soda.Price, .Name = cb.Name}
```